# \addcontentsline and unwanted indentation

Tags: table-of-contents

I am struggling to do some changes in the ToC. Below a simple sample.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Part I}
\section{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }

\end{document}
```

The ToC created with this code is shown in the figure below
[image]

My question is: Is there a easy way to avoid the indentation in ToC when `\addcontentsline` is used?

Bonus question: Is there a way to hide the page number in ToC for chapters containing `\section` and `\subsection`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Bernard should the last one be `titletoc`?

Comment: @dalif;: yes, sorry for the typo. I'll rewrite my comment since I can't edit it now. Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at the dedicated packages: `etoc, tocloft` and `titletoc` (which comes with titlesec).

Answer (score 2):

Alter the `\l@subsection` value from the `book.cls` file can meet the expectaion, and the `MWE` is:

```
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{0em}}
\makeatother
```

But, it is better to achieve the requirement by using either `tocloft` or `titletoc` as suggested by `Bernard`...